# Weka Exception Cobweb No attributes

Tags: java, weka

I m writing a little pice of code in weka which apply a filter and then apply a clustering algorithm but i get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" weka.core.WekaException: weka.clusterers.Cobweb: No attributes!

Code:

what is wrong with this??:

```
    StringToWordVector stringToWordVector = new StringToWordVector();
    // bigrams to 4-grams
    NGramTokenizer nGramTokenizer = new NGramTokenizer();
    nGramTokenizer.setNGramMinSize(2);
    nGramTokenizer.setNGramMinSize(4);
    stringToWordVector.setTokenizer(nGramTokenizer);

    // TF-IDF
    stringToWordVector.setTFTransform(true);
    stringToWordVector.setIDFTransform(true);
    stringToWordVector.setUseStoplist(true);
    stringToWordVector.setLowerCaseTokens(true);


    ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(new File("./learningRelation.arff"));
    Instances structure = loader.getStructure();

    stringToWordVector.setInputFormat(structure);
    structure = Filter.useFilter(structure, stringToWordVector);
    structure.setClassIndex(TestInstances.NO_CLASS);


    Cobweb cw = new Cobweb();
    cw.buildClusterer(structure);

    Instance current;
    while ((current = loader.getNextInstance(structure)) != null)
          cw.updateClusterer(current);

     cw.updateFinished();

        // output generated model
     System.out.println(cw);
```

the file learingRelation.arff is like this:

@relation Tweets

@attribute tweet string

@data

'Social Commerce -  Presentation | scoopit via ronsela http://t.co/LrGHQKrmOQ Social eCommerce Marketing'

'Social Commerce -  Presentation | scoopit via ronsela http://t.co/LrGHQKrmOQ Social eCommerce Marketing'

Comment: Ok sorry guys i have solved was wrong the path of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved, the mistake was the wrong path of the file:

```
    loader.setFile(new File("./learningRelation.arff"));
```